# Best Character for splitting Android

Tags: android, split

I started an android project, just like chat program. 
Data downloaded from my server just like this

```
1~my name~my username~message
```

Nah, my question is, is there any character that compatible with android
to replace the delimiter (~) above. Im afraid, if in other day, user use the 
character ~, program will crashed.

I used character ÷, but my android cant read it, it turned to '?'.
Did someone had the same problem ??

Comment: use JSON or XML than using some special symbols.

Comment: Downloaded how???  Any reason to not use JSON??

Comment: This is some bad programming but when I need to do such a thing I use multiple delimeters, like ~~~

Comment: iNan & HotLicks : I never use JSON before, is it easy to do ?
yygyt : thats sounds great. Does split() support multiple delimiters ?

Comment: JSON is very very simple data interchange, there are various tutorials out there, just google n c :)

Comment: I would choose JSON too. There are a plenty of tutorials about JSON. And you should consider using stringtokenizer in the latter case. e.g. "StringTokenizer(<STRING>, "~|~");"

Comment: @yygyt does this works ? split("~~~"); ?

Comment: @FelixAnggaErlandhita I really haven't tried it. I just use StringTokenizer for splitting purposes. Here is an example:

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(clicked, "~|~");
String to = st.nextToken();
String from = st.nextToken();

Comment: Hi, it works, I've tried it :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is almost bad idea to create your own format for client-server communication, my best advice is to give a shot to json or xml. There are lots of library available both on client side and server side to form/parse them all you have to do is use you back-end language to return either one of the format.

For python : http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

For php : http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

For Android : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

You can easily find other languages with simple search.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using also Java on the server side, you could define an object like `ChatMessage` and just send it per `Socket` and an [`Object Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html) to the Server.

As Burak noted, your way is the wrong way... but there are several other ways, IMHO an object stream might be the easiest solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a delimiter which is a possible content of the data put into the flow you are delimiting, you will have a problem.

To prevent that, you need to prevent the character from occurring in a way that could be misinterpreted.

1. At the input side, detect occurrences and replace them either with a special code, or with an escaping prefix character, or quote the contents (though then you have to handle literal occurences of the quote characters)
2. If you use an escaping character, your splitting code must ignore any delimiter following an escape character or within a quoted sequence.
3. At the output side you should replace the codes or escape sequences with a literal instance of the encoded character or remove any quoting characters.

As others have mentioned, there are a number of standard schemes and functions for handling them.